# What is the meaning of the word "vallaque" in the French Wikipedia page on Avignon's history?

Tags: france, language, early-medieval, franks

The Wikipedia page [Histoire d'Avignon](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histoire_d%27Avignon#Haut_Moyen_%C3%82ge), contains a passage refering to the  Frankish king of Austrasia [Sigebert I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigebert_I). He was seeking access to the sea, so that he forced the conquest of a piece of land conecting Auvergne to Marseilles, through Avignon. That "Austrasian corridor" is also called "vallaque".

*"l’Austrasie est l’apanage de Sigebert Ier. Comme l’Austrasie n’a pas de débouché vers la Méditerranée, Sigebert s’ouvre un passage. ... un « couloir austrasien » (ou **vallaque**) est forcé qui relie l’Auvergne à Marseille coupant en deux la Burgondie de Gondran. Ce passage perdure trente-deux ans."*

*"Ce couloir austrasien ou **vallaque** se repère encore par la toponymie ... ... dans les Bouches-du-Rhône ... ... Velaux (**Vallacus** + suffixe onem)"*

---

*"Austrasia is the apanage of Sigebert I. As Austrasia has no outlet to the Mediterranean, Sigebert opens a passage. ... an "Austrasian (or **Vallaque**) corridor" is forced, connecting Auvergne to Marseilles cutting in two Burgundy of Gondran. This passage lasts thirty-two years."*

*"This Austrasian or **Vallaque** corridor is still identified by toponymy ... ... in the Bouches-du-Rhône ... ...Velaux (**Vallacus** + suffix `onem`)"*

---

Looking at the Wikipedia page on the village of [Velaux](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velaux) the name of which is said to reflect that *Vallaque/Vallacus* connection, there is no discussion on etymology (although the toponym *Vallat* is mentioned (*"c'est le mot local pour désigner les ruisseaux et rivières*" = local word to name streams and rivers), but without other details.

[Velaux' etymology](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Velaux) on Wiktionary is absent, but the image there (as well as the Wikipedia page at the previous link) clearly say that the Occitan name is *Velaurs* - which seem to weaken the connection to *Vallacus*, whatever that is.

I am not able to find this word in the other Wikipedia pages relating to the same events, not even in other internet searches on that "corridor". It is absent in dictionaries like [CNRTL](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vallaque).

Comment: My French is ... limited, but I wonder if there is a relation to terms like [Valaques](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valaques) (people from [Wallachia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallachia)) or the related adjective [valaque](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/valaque). Those seem to be derived from a Slavic term for people speaking languages derived from Latin (« peuple roman », see also "Romania"). Maybe the idea here was similar, to call the « couloir austrasien » the corridor "to where the Romans used to live", "to the Roman lands" or similar. Just a speculation, though.

Comment: Perhaps better on [french.stackexchange.com](https://french.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: *If* this is not solved as a language issue, researching the 'Austrasian Corridor' led to a footnote [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=6PKPDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA57&dq=%22Austrasian%22+corridor&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_ysKI4pz9AhUgO0QIHQKVA1UQ6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=%22Austrasian%22%20corridor&f=false) listing quite a few refences concerning *the characterization of Sigibert's territories as an "Austrasian corridor"*. I tried the [Loseby article  in JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/301290) but it is not open to read, and it seems to reference Duprat anyways.

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/a/52463/3728